# Forced to execute assetic dump on development mode in Symfony2 with virtual hosts

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, symfony, virtualhost

I'm trying to find a way to solve my problem but I don't find any solution. I'll try to explain the better I can.

I'm developing my website in a local environment, on a MAMP server. The home URL is `http://localhost:8888/mysite/web/app_dev.php`. I wanted to change it to `http://site.dev` for the dev mode (later, I will use `http://site.prod` for the prod mode). Some of you will ask me "why ?". The answer is that we want (the other developers and I) to have the same kind of URL than in my production like `http://example.com`

So, I looked on the side of the Apache's virtual hosts and the host file on my computer. I changed the Apache port to 80 and the MySQL port to 3306 (Nginx is 80 by default too).

Here is the `httpd-vhosts.conf` file :

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /Applications/MAMP/htdocs
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName site.dev
    ServerAlias www.site.dev

    DocumentRoot /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/site/web
    <Directory /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/site/web>
        AllowOverride All
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

The `hosts` file :

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost 
fe80::1%lo0     localhost

127.0.0.1       site.dev
```

Obviously, I activate the vhosts in my apache `httpd.conf` file :

```
# Virtual hosts
Include /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

Here is my new `web/.htaccess` file :

```
DirectoryIndex app_dev.php

<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    RewriteRule ^app\.php(/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$2 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    RewriteRule ^app_dev\.php(/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$2 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule .? - [L]

    RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/app_dev.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /app_dev.php/
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Now, I go on `http://site.dev`, everything works fine.
I make a changement in my `script.js` file (for example), then, I refresh my home page. Nothing changed... I try to execute `php app/console assetic:dump`, I refresh one more time, and, miracle, everything works.

So, my question is the following one : How can I use my `http://site.dev` virtual host WITHOUT the need of executing the `assetic:dump` console function.

Thank you

EDIT : I didn't find a solution to my problem, so, I will give you more details :
- When I go on `http://localhost/site/`, I see all the directories and files of the root directory.
- When I go on `http://localhost/site/web/`, all the website is displayed but there are missing images (bad path in twig or less files) and I have to execute `assetic:dump`.
- When I go on `http://localhost/site/web/app_dev.php`, everything is refreshed instantly...

Answer (score 0):

```
php app/console assets:install web --symlink
```

This should symlink your assets, so you wont need to re-run the asset command each time .

Also, check out http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-6-smarter-assets-install-command

Comment: Already done million times, obviously..
Thanks for the edit, I will take a look

Comment: so you are saying,   symlinks dont work on your system ? EDIT: what are the locations of your assets?

Comment: They work perfectly without the http://site.dev URL...
The location of my assets : web/

Comment: and your symfony profiler is showing that you are, in fact, in your dev env ?    (your 100% sure you're actually viewing app_dev.php,   not app.php)

Comment: Yes, I have the debug toolbar and it shows me : dev.
EDIT : by the way, all other developers, even on WAMP environment, have the same problem.

Comment: so if you just use,   localhost/app_dev.php,     the assets are refreshing correctly ?     if so,    try this:     without app_dev, does the actual asset on disk change ? but the one in cache does not,   or does the generated asset not change at all,   ON DISK (nevermind what you see in browser)

Comment: I didn't find a solution to my problem, so, I will answer you better. When I go on `http://localhost/site/`, I see all the directories and files of the root directory. When I go on `http://localhost/site/web/`, all the website is displayed but there are missing images (bad path in twig or less files) and I have to execute `assetic:dump`. When I go on `http://localhost/site/web/app_dev.php`, everything is refreshed instantly...